# Data Replication between two Neo4J databases

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, neo4j, etl

I have one Neo4j production database, and Disaster Recovery database. Every week end, the data in Production should make available in Disaster Recovery database. 
I have only read permission in Production database. Could anyone have insights on this. I can use any Bigdata Tech stack to achive this. Is there any way to use 
Hadoop,Spark etc to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2):

This may be too obvious but why don't you [take a backup and restore it in the DRP environment ?](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup/)

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: is there any way to automate the process? As i have to do this every week

Comment: Absolutely. Neo4j (EE) allows a remote backup. So you can actually have a simple script on the DRP server that stops it's current copy, pulls in a backup of the live database and starts again (maybe in readonly mode to make sure it doesn't get updated afterwards).